# Nautilus context menu option to create new file

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I use [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nautilus) 3.10.1 on [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) 7.0 GNU/Linux. In context menu, there is no such option like create new file/document. So, I want to add such an option (which may work like that of existing option: `New folder`).

- Is there any nautilus plug-in available? or
- I have [Nautilus Action Configuration Tool](http://packages.trisquel.info/belenos/nautilus-actions) installed. So, what command/script I can use for this purpose?

<sup>Further I am also interested in featuring options like: New [Writer](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/) Document, New [Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) Document, etc.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access `Nautilus`help (click on `Files` on top bar then select `Help`) and then navigate to `Tips and questions` > `Templates for commonly-used document types`:

[image: screen-shot]

There is something missing from the documentation: you have to add your `Templates` location to your `xdg-user-dirs`, e.g. if you set your templates dir as `~/Templates` you'll have to add the following line

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.
You then follow the help instructions to create templates (e.g. after placing an empty text file named `New Text Document` and an empty writer document named `New Writer Document` in `Templates` you'll get a new context menu option named `New Document` which will expand to `New Text Document` and `New Writer Document`)