# Setting an XDG_DIR as a child folder of another XDG_DIR

Tags: xdg-user-dirs

I am configuring my linux user environment by editing the configuration file located at `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` .

Here is a snippet of my configuration:

```bsh
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/docs" #originally "$HOME/Documents"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/docs/templates" #originally "$HOME/Templates"
```

Is this a valid configuration?

Comment: Usually XDG_*_DIRs can be nested though in your particular case, setting  DOCUMENTS as a child of TEMPLATES will also cause your context-menu for `New Document` to display an additional menu `templates` that will expand to all your documents in DOCUMENTS (i.e. `$HOME/docs/templates`). So the answer is "yes", it's a valid configuration but with the mentioned side effects; why would you want to have your docs in `templates` and your templates in `docs` ?

Comment: @don_crissti thanks! Good point, I had a bit of dyslexia there when I wrote `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/docs/templates"` in this post. I've edited my post to reflect what I intended.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "cause your context-menu for X to display an additional menu"

Comment: The `TEMPLATES` is a directory where you place your _templates_ so that you can access them [via context-menu when you want to create a new document](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226605). Sure, now that you edited your post my first comment no longer applies. Anyway, as I said, it is a valid configuration.