# Add 'Create launcher' to Nautilus context menu (without `gnome-desktop-item-edit`)

Tags: nautilus, menu, desktop-shortcuts

The idea is to be able to create a shortcut from context menu in order to access an application or even an internet link.

The `gnome-desktop-item-edit` (as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/47206)) depends on the `gnome-panel` package that is not available on all systems.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **Create a new template file for a launcher**

As indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226605/nautilus-context-menu-option-to-create-new-file), the `~/Templates` folder can be used to add new options under the context menu 'New document'.

[image]

So:

> gedit ~/Templates/New Launcher.desktop

with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=
Icon=
Categories=System;Settings;
Exec=
Terminal=false
```

[image]

Open it as text, fill the different lines as desired and save. For an internet link, write something like `Exec=firefox <your link>`.

Then, double click it and select "Trust and launch" to see the proper name.

Answer (score 0):

### How to Install gnome-desktop-item-edit

1. Download deb package for your architecture at https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome-panel
2. Extract package...
3. cd gnome-panel_3.8.1-7+b1_amd64/usr/bin
4. sudo cp gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/bin/
5. Done.

Comment: isn't it `gnome-panel_3.8.1-7+b1_amd64/data/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit`?

Comment: @cipricus ofc it is :)